# transfer damage based on the selected object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There are three scripts
1)Checks the mouse click on the object (unit), if it is a unit, then the backlight is turned on, this object is recorded in the target mob s variable. (everything is cool here, I even passed the targetmobs variable to the 2 script)

2. if the space key is pressed, then we must damage the selected target (based on targetmobs)(not working)
3. here are the characteristics of the unit (in particular health)

The problem is in accessing the variable based on the selected object
I attach the code

1)

```
public class Select : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool IsActive ;
    public Camera selectCamera;
    public GameObject[] mobs;
    public GameObject targetmobs;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    bool selecting = false;
    private float selectTimer = 0f;

   


    void Awake()
    {

        mobs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Skelet");
    }


    void Start()
    {
         


    }


    void Update()
    {
        
        Debug.Log(IsActive);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            
                CheckIfUnderMouse();

            


        }
    }


    public void CheckIfUnderMouse()
    {
        Ray ray = selectCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100f))
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Skelet")
            {
                targetmobs = hit.collider.gameObject;

                targetmobs.GetComponentInChildren<SelectableCharacter>().TurnOnSelector();


                testdamagetounits.target = targetmobs;

                Debug.Log("нажал и выбрал");

                IsActive = true;


            }
            else
            {
                IsActive = false;

                if(targetmobs != null)
                {
                    targetmobs.GetComponentInChildren<SelectableCharacter>().TurnOffSelector();
                    targetmobs = null;
                    testdamagetounits.target = null;
                }
                
                Debug.Log("нажал в пустоту");
            }
            
            


        }

    }
    



}
```

2. 

```
public class testdamagetounits : MonoBehaviour
{


    int randomNumber;
    int lastNumber;
    int meleeDamage = 5;
    int takedamage;


    public static GameObject target;
    

    void Start()
    {
        target = null;
        randomNumber = Random.Range(0, 5);

    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        Randomize();
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {


            tuTarget();





        }


        }

    void Randomize()
    {
        randomNumber = Random.Range(0, 5);
        if (randomNumber == lastNumber)
        {
            randomNumber = Random.Range(0, 5);
        }
        lastNumber = randomNumber;


    }
    void tuTarget()
    {

        if(target != null)
        {

           

            

        }

    }

    
}
```

3. 

```
public class Target : MonoBehaviour
{

    
    int randomNumber;
    int lastNumber;

    int damage;



    public TextMeshProUGUI TextHealth;
    public  TextMeshProUGUI TextDamage;
    public TargetHealthBar healthBar;

    [Header("Характеристики")]  
    public   int maxHealth = 122;
    public   int currentHealth;



    
    
    
    
    

    
    void Start()
    {
        
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
        SelectHealth.currentHealth = currentHealth;
        SelectHealth.maxHealth = maxHealth;

        TextHealth.text = currentHealth.ToString()+ "/"+maxHealth.ToString();
        
    }

    void Update()
    {


        TakeDamage();

    }

    void TakeDamage()
    {
        
        if(currentHealth <=0 )
        {
        
        }
        else
        {
            currentHealth -= damage;

            TextDamage.text = "-" + damage.ToString();
        }

        healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
        TextHealth.text = currentHealth.ToString()+ "/"+maxHealth.ToString();
        


    }
    
}
```

пробовал разные обращения через  GetComponentInChildren().
но увы я новичок в программировании

Comment: Please use English here on StackOveflow

Comment: Make your question clear, if you want to access a gamobject's script use GetComponent

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.